# как в LyX изменять названия элементов интерфейса, всплывающих подсказок для элементов интерфейса?

Tags: lyx

Никто не может подсказать случайно?

Answer (score 0):

А делается это так.  Вот, когда используешь LyX на языке, отличном от английского, отображаемые названия различных меню, элементов меню, панелей инструментов и т. д. одним словом, отображаемые названия почти всех элементов интерфейса, кроме выпадающего списка окружений и, возможно, чего-то еще, переводы различных сообщений берутся программой LyX из файла `.mo`, соответствующего используемому языку. Вот сколько я ни ставил различные копии программы LyX, эти файлы `.mo`, во всяком случае, в рамках используемой копии LyX для различных языков имеют одинаковые имена. В копии программы, используемой мной сейчас, эти файлы называются *LyX2.0.mo*. Эти файлы для различных языков отличаются, помимо своего содержания еще и тем, что они находятся в различных подпапках одной и той же папки. Для русского языка соответствующий файл *LyX2.0.mo* находится в `C:\Program Files\LyX 2.0\Resources\locale\ru\LC_MESSAGES`. Однако, если с целью пробы заменить в окне программы LyX, отображаемое название там, какой-нибудь панели инструментов какого-нибудь пункта какого-нибудь меню, изменить соответствующее место в файле `.mo` (как найти это место рассказано ниже), это, после сохранений изменений в файле `.mo` при перезапуске LyX, вопреки ожиданиям, приведет не к изменению названия соответствующего элемента интерфейса, а к отображению вообще всех названий, всплывающих подсказок на английском языке: редактировать файл `.mo` напрямую не имеет смысла. А нужно редактировать файл `.po`, из которого впоследствии с помощью программы *gettext* после каждого его изменения (с последующим сохранением этого изменения) получают заново файл `.mo` и перемещают с заменой вновь полученный файл `.mo` в папку, названную выше. Остановимся подробнее на этом процессе. Вначале скачиваем [gettext](https://mlocati.github.io/articles/gettext-iconv-windows.html). я по приведенной ссылке нажимал для скачивания 32-битный *static*, причем не на значок с компьютером и диском, а на значок папки на молнии. Скачали архив, распаковали куда угодно. Чтобы папку bin этой программы из-за такой мелочи в РАТН не добавлять, мы сделаем следующее: пойдем [сюда](ftp://ftp.lyx.org/pub/lyx/stable/2.3.x/). Отсюда скачиваем файл *lyx-2.3.2.tar.gz*. Откроем его, из папки *po* скопируем в папку bin ранее распакованной программы gettext файл *ru.po*, переименуем его в *LyX2.0.po*. Далее мы открываем этот файл *.po* в каком-нибудь текстовом редакторе. Так. Вот мы захотеил изменить, например, отображаемое название пункта **Закладки** меню **Навигация** на **Закладки: измененное отображение**. Ага, открываем меню **Навигация**, смотрим на название пунктов этого меню рядом с пунктом **Закладки**. Эти пункты, например, такие: **Следующая заметка**, **Следующее изменение**,... это нужно потому, что в файле `.po` могут в нескольких разных местах стоять одинаковые переводы отображаемых названий элементов интерфейса, из-за чего так же будет и в полученном файле `.mo`, что приведет к тому, что в окне LyX несколько элементов интерфейса в разных местах будут иметь одинаковые отображаемые названия. Так вот, чтобы в файле `.po` изменить перевод какого-нибудь элемента интерфейса, чтобы в файле .mo изменились отображаемые названия точно тех элементов интерфейса, отображаемые названия которых изменить нужно, нам и нужно посмотреть на отображаемые названия элементов, соседних с теми элементами интерфейса, отображаемые названия мы изменить собираемся. Если в окне программы LyX у какого-нибудь элемента есть всплывающая подсказка, отображаемый на соответствующем языке текст этой подсказки в файле `.po` будет располагаться недалеко от отображаемого названия этого элемента интерфейса. Еще один признак места файла `.po`, которое нужно редактировать, чтобы это привело к изменению отображаемого названия того элемента интерфейса, у которого отображаемое название изменить и нужно. Итак, переходим в окно редактора с открытым файлом LyX2.0.po, поиском находим там *Закладки*, смотрим на соседние участки на русском языке. Вот один из результатов поиска вместе со своим окружением:

```
#: 
src/frontends/qt4/ui/PDFSupportUi.ui:249
msgid "Bibliographical backreferences"
msgstr "Обратные библиографические ссылки"

#: 
src/frontends/qt4/ui/PDFSupportUi.ui:252
msgid "B&ackreferences:"
msgstr "&Обратные ссылки:"

#: 
src/frontends/qt4/ui/PDFSupportUi.ui:281
msgid "&Bookmarks"
msgstr "&Закладки"

#: 
src/frontends/qt4/ui/PDFSupportUi.ui:293
msgid "G&enerate bookmarks (toc)"
msgstr "&Создавать закладки"

#:  
src/frontends/qt4/ui/PDFSupportUi.ui:314
msgid "&Numbered bookmarks"
msgstr "&Нумерованные закладки"
```

Это найденное слово *Закладки* находится в строке с номером 3144. Судя по соседним словам на русском языке, это не то, что нужно. А вот другой результат поиска слова *Закладки* вместе с некоторым своим окружением в файле *LyX2.0.po*:

```
#: lib/ui/stdmenus.inc:559
msgid "Reject All Changes|e"
msgstr "Отклонить все изменения"

#: lib/ui/stdmenus.inc:560
msgid "Show Changes in Output|S"
msgstr "Показать изменения на выводе"

#: lib/ui/stdmenus.inc:567
msgid "Bookmarks|B"
msgstr "Закладки|З"

#: lib/ui/stdmenus.inc:568
msgid "Next Note|N"
msgstr "Следующая заметка|С"

#: lib/ui/stdmenus.inc:569
msgid "Next Change|C"
msgstr "Следующее изменение|щ"
```

Находится это вхождение слова *Закладки* в строке с номером 19619 и, судя по словам русского языка, находящимся в окрестности этого вхождения, это то, что нужно. Заменяем это вхождение слова на то словосочетание, предложение, которое мы хотим, чтобы служило отображаемым именем соответствующего элемента интерфейса. Таким образом, этот участок кода вместе с некоторой своей окрестностью в файле LyX2.0.po начинает выглядеть так:

```
#: lib/ui/stdmenus.inc:559
msgid "Reject All Changes|e"
msgstr "Отклонить все изменения"

#: lib/ui/stdmenus.inc:560
msgid "Show Changes in Output|S"
msgstr "Показать изменения на выводе"

#: lib/ui/stdmenus.inc:567
msgid "Bookmarks|B"
msgstr "Закладки: измененное отображение|З"

#: lib/ui/stdmenus.inc:568
msgid "Next Note|N"
msgstr "Следующая заметка|С"

#: lib/ui/stdmenus.inc:569
msgid "Next Change|C"
msgstr "Следующее изменение|щ"
```

Сохраняем изменения в LyX2.0.po. [Запускаем командную строку в папке](https://remontka.pro/open-command-line-windows-10/) bin, в которой находимся. В окне этой строки пишем следующую команду:

```
msgfmt LyX2.0.po --o LyX2.0.mo
```

, нажимаем клавишу `Enter`. После этого, как и следовало ожидать, в папке bin появляется файл LyX2.0.mo. Лично я, чтобы по сто раз не вводить одну и ту же команду в командную строку, в папке bin создал батник следующего содержания:

```
cd /d %0\..
msgfmt LyX2.0.po --o LyX2.0.mo
```

И теперь, когда я его открываю после сохранения изменений в файле LyX2.0.po, у меня в папке bin создается точно такой же файл LyX2.0.mo, как если бы я его получил из командной строки. Далее перемещаем, повторюсь с заменой, полученный файл `.mo` в папку `C:\Program Files\LyX 2.0\Resources\locale\ru\LC_MESSAGES`. После перезапуска LyX получаеи следующее:
[image]