# Как в LyX добавить/убрать сообщения какой-либо группы сообщений в View Messages?

Tags: lyx

Вот, когда через **Вид>View Meseages** (или через **Вид>Просмотреть сообщения** - название зависит от [используемого файла локализации *LyX2.0.mo*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1064164/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-lyx-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC)) открываешь в нижней части окна прогры LyX область *Сообщения прогресса/отладки*, в этой части окна бывает чрезмерно много выводится сообщений, бывает, просто мышкой пошевелишь, а там выводится километровая последовательность строк, в которой отыскать что-то нужное (например, чтобы получить подсказку, как вводить ту или иную команду через [Буфер команды](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1066002/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5-lyx-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%8B), там оно будет, конечно, не в буквальной форме, но подсказку это дать может, я, быть может, скоро немного об этом расскажу, что мне удалось накопать по этому поводу) бывает крайне затруднительно. Может быть, можно как-то регулировать количество этих сообщений?

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы уменьшить (или, наоборот, добавить сообщения какой-либо группы сообщений), делаем вот что. В той нижней области окна щелкаем левой кнопкой мышки *Натройки*, там переключатель *Отладочные сообщения* устанавливаем в *Выделенное*:

[image]

А потом тут же в правой части выполняем двойной щелчок (с такой скоростью, с которой это делается при открытии какого-нибудь файла, эту скорость при необходимости можно изменить в настройках самого компа, вне прогры LyX) по группе сообщений, сообщения из которой мы хотим сделать не отображающимися в области Сообщения прогресса/отладки или, наоборот, сообщения этой группы сообщений мы хотим сделать отображающимися в этой области. После этого двойного щелчка статус группы сообщений, например, *Общая информация*, *Инициализация программы*, меняется на противоположный: если до двойного щелчка он был Да, то после этого двойного щелчка он станет Нет и сообщения этой группы перестают отображаться в этой области окна прогры LyX и наоборот. Все, щелкаем по *Вывод* и наслаждаемся работой в программе, в которой еще один момент удалось настроить так, как нужно нам.