# Изменение рабочего поля программы LyX

Tags: lyx

Dот, например, в окне программы LyX числа, нумерующие пункты окружения нумерация, отображаются таким же цветом, как и весь остальной текст, а мы, допустим, хотим сделать их красного цвета, или, например, слово *Теорема*, появляющееся при переходе в одноименное окружение мы хотим сделать в самом окне прогры LyX пишущимися наклонными, не прямыми, как это обычно, буквами зеленого цвета. А еще предположим, мы хотим сделать буквы обычного текста синими. Есть ли возможность для осуществления чего-то подобного?

Answer (score 0):

Есть. В качестве иллюстрации этого я покажу, как добиться целей, названных в вопросе этой темы. Итак. Идем в **Документ>Настройки>Локальный макет** (в зависимости от используемого [файла локализации .mo](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1064164/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-lyx-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC/1064165#1064165)  вместо Локальный макет может стоять Local layout), там пишем вот что:

```
Provides amsmath 0
PageStyle plain
Style Standard
Font
Color blue
EndFont
End

Style Enumerate
Font
Color red
EndFont
End

Style Theorem
Font
Color green
Shape ital
EndFont
End
```

Нажимаем кнопку *Проверить*, через некоторое время, если там все написали как надо, справа от этой кнопки появляется надпись **Макет без ошибок!**, все, нажимаем кнопку `OK` (ну, или `Применить`). Окно прогры LyX начинает выглядеть так:

[image]

Так, еще, как видно из приведенного кода, через *Локальный макет* можно что-то делать (скорее всего, естественно, отключать/подключать, что именно меня, во всяком случае сейчас, мало интересует, я это привел лишь в качестве иллюстрации того, что еще можно писать в Локальном макете) и с пакетами LATEX. Далее, изменение макета в одном файле `.lyx` совершенно не влияет на отображение других файлов `.lyx` в окне прогры LyX (если вы после того, как что-то вписали в текстовое поле Локального макета не нажимали кнопку 
`Сохранить как параметры документа по умолчанию`). Скажу еще, что особо я в эту тему не вникал, ну, и то, что я здесь написал, вполне хватит для раскрутки в этом направлении. А вообще, про то, что можно там писать, можно (частично) прочитать, во-первых, там, где написано, внизу на фото, а, во-вторых, как мне сейчас известно, образцы форм записей туда команд можно подсмотреть в файлах папки `C:\Program Files\LyX 2.0\Resources\layouts`.

Comment: Кто редактировал название этого поста? Получилось вообще ни к селу, ни к городу. Я сам, когда у себя в  сообщениях это увидел, не понял, о чем вообще это. Только, когда открыл, стало ясно. Не редактируйте, пожалуйста, мои посты про LyX! Большинство из вас вообще не имеют представления, о чем я пишу!